# Form submit alternative url in case of error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched high and low and did not find any solution for this...

I want to implement a login form where in case the first url fails [mainly 404 or 5xx errors], it tries the second automaticly.

I did it on server-side but cookies on another domains are involved so i cannot pass their values into the browser...

So my aproach was using javascript so it's the browser who deals with the petitions.

```js
$('#loginForm button').on('click', function(e) {

  if (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  try {
    $('loginForm button').submit();
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }

  var varEmail = $('#email').val();
  var varPassword = $('#password').val();



  var dataForm = {
    email: varEmail,
    password: varPassword
  };


  $.post(mainURL, dataForm).fail(
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $.post(alternativeURL, dataForm).done(
        function(data) {
          window.location.pathname = data._tapestry.redirectURL; //Tapestry involved
        }

      );
    }
  ).done(
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      //????    
    }

  );



});
```

This works for the failing case (404 or 500) but when the results are a:

- 200 (External page redirects to one of their forms): I have the html in the answer and if i try document write, their css are not loaded correctly as they are in their domain.
- 302 (The petition is redirected back to my domain): The fail handler is triggered.

Edit:

My Desired functionality is that the first post ends up in a redirect or an error. I want to follow that redirect.

Comment: check the status code and make another post request accordingly? It's not really clear what the issue is. You clearly know how to make another post request. What exactly is giving you trouble?

Comment: "I did it on server-side but cookies on another domains are involved so i cannot pass their values into the browser..." Javascript will only have access to the current domain's cookies too...

Comment: so you want to read the redirect header value from the response, and then redirect to it?

Comment: Yes, I researched i bit more and i've seen the error is that the redirect is done to another domain... ajax and the Xmlhttprequest don't like that very much